# CAS Authentication in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cas

I have a website on Node.js and CAS server. I need to build a client, which will redirect unauthorized user to CAS Server and than if successful, it redirects to the requested path but with his info: login,role and etc. Which library or framework can you recommend to me for these purposes?

Comment: You can use `axios` library for calling the CAS Server API endpoint. Otherwise, you don't need any library I think. `axios` on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0):

A modest google search would lead one to [passport-cas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-cas). It provides *CAS authentication strategies for Passport*. You can read about the Passport library [here](http://www.passportjs.org/).